# MediaPlayer instance: stop behaves like a pause

Tags: android, media-player

I wrote a small music playback control test application. I have a play, pause, stop and rewind button. My issue is that that
     player.stop();
is behaving the same exact way as
     player.pause();
I am calling player.prepare() right after player.stop() so that i can have the player instance ready for start() operation.

I do not see any errors [IOexceptions or IllegalStateExceptions] being raised while calling the prepare() after i do a stop(). Also, i am not calling any seekTo(0) after stop(). So, i am not setting the position back to the beginning of the song.

I am using a Nexus Google One phone running 2.3.4.

Any idea if i am doing something stupid or if what i am observing is actually how the state machine was built.

TIA.

Comment: Its been three years since you asked the questions , and mine doubt is also the same . . .I just wanted to check weather they have updated the api's so that after stop it begins from starting?

Comment: @user3726986 pls look at my comments in the thread that has "accepted" answer. That was back in 2011. It should still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doesn't the state diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
states that stop means "stay in stopped state" ?

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
>
> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.
> Calling stop() has no effect on a MediaPlayer object that is already in the Stopped state.

There's no affirmation that `stop()` should change the `CurrentPosition`.

There's no affirmation that calling the `prepare()` should change the `CurrentPosition`.

So, to go to the beginning of the music, you should mannualy set its position.

But I agree with you. Since the `pause()` method states it will resume playing from the current position, I'd expect it get back to the beginning when `stop()` is called.

And it has some impact when you need to call the `prepare()`

> For example, the call to prepare() can take a long time to execute, because it might involve fetching and decoding media data.

so `stop()` needs to call `prepare()` that can make it take longer, while `pause()` has less impact: you can call the `start()` right after.

Comment: Question is when you go from stopped state to prepared state and then call start(), do we expect the song to start from the beginning or from the point where the player was stopped. I feel it should start from the beginning but i am observing it's starting from the point where it was stopped. So, it makes me think there is no difference between stop() and pause(). Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It's how I would expect it to behave, but... take a look that `stop` doesn't make it go to another position (there's nothing saying that it would go). And getCurrentPosition() works even in the stopped state.

Comment: hhmm... i would expect getCurrentPosition() in stopped state to return 0. so, what's the difference between pause()? and stop()? why have two states that essentially functions the same way. Agreed that you don't need to call prepare() after pause(). But from the user's perspective, there is no difference in these two states. Thanks woliveirajr.

Comment: Thanks. For now, i will manually reset the position via seekTo() after: So, the sequence will be stop()-->prepare()-->seekTo(0) and that will suit my need :)

Comment: Hi! I tried this sequence aswell and it works, but when I click on play again I hear a little bit of music before it seeks to the 0 position... why is that?

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth : strange, seems that there is some buffer, somewhere in the api or in the app...

Comment: I use mp.pause(); and mp.seekTo(0);

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be a bug, because the API documentation for the MediaPlayer start method suggests the behavior that you expect:

> public void start ()
>
> Starts or resumes playback. If playback had previously been paused,
>   playback will continue from where it was paused. If playback had been
>   stopped, or never started before, playback will start at the
>   beginning.

For the time being, explicitly calling seekTo(0) once the player is prepared seems to be a reasonable workaround.