# Android : how to know if MediaPlayer is paused?

Tags: java, android, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

`MediaPlayer.isPlaying()` does not allow to know if the `MediaPlayer` is stopped or paused. How to know if it is paused and not stopped?

Thanks !

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849205/2009591)

Answer (score 20):

One way to do this is to check if the media player it not playing (paused) and check if it is at a position other than the starting position (1).

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

Boolean isPaused = !mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 1;
```

Comment: Docs say that getCurrentPosition return "the current position in milliseconds".  If you've never put the mediaPlayer in pause, it will be a huge number like 1628054332 or similar (probably system time in millis since 1970). So to take care of the first time the user plays (without previously using pause) you will have to introduce a flag of some sorts.

Answer (score 5):

There is no API to check if `MediaPlayer` is paused or not. So please use any Boolean variable to check and toggle it when you paused using any `button`.

```
onClick(){
 if(isPaused)
  {
    //resume media player
    isPaused = false;
  }else{
   // pause it
     isPaused = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is no such method, then How you are going to set value of isPaused variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Define a `boolean` variable called `playedAtLeastOnce` (or whatever you want) then set it to `true` if your `MediaPlayer` object has been played at least for one time. A good place to assign it to true is in `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method from `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` implemented interface.

Then if `MediaPlayer` is not playing and *`playedAtLeastOnce`* is `true`, you can say that `MedaiPlayer` is paused.

```
boolean playedAtLeastOnce;

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    playedAtLeastOnce = true;
}

public boolean isPaused() {
    if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying && playedAtLeastOnce)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    // or you can do it like this
    // return !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying && playedAtLeastOnce;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variable

```
private boolean notIdle = false;
```

After you `setDataSource()`, in the listener `setOnPreparedListener()`

```
notIdle = true;
```

Override `MediaPlayer.reset()` funtion, inside it

```
notIdle = false;
```

`notIdle` will be `true` in `start()`, `pause()` and `stop()` states... you can change this behaviour as you consider more convinient.

Answer (score -1):

As Ankit answered there is no API to check whether Media Player is paused or not ,we have to check it programmatically like this

```
private boolean pause=true; //A Boolean variable to check your state declare it true or false here depends upon your requirement
```

Now you can make a method here to check that whenever you want to check player is pause

```
public void checkplayer(MediaPlayer player){
if(isPause=true)   //check your declared state if you set false or true here
Player.pause();
else if(isPause=false){
Player.play();
 or 
Player.stop();
}
```