# Android MediaPlayer Fails on API 21 (but NOT API 19 or 22!)

Tags: android, audio, crash, buffer, android-mediaplayer

In my app, I would like to have a simple method that uses the MediaPlayer class to play a sound resource once (and again, if needed).

I have successfully achieved this (see code below) and successfully tested it on a real hardware device with API 23, and also on emulators with API levels from 19 all the way to P... *EXCEPT FOR API 21, WHERE IT FAILS.*

Isn't that weird? Why would something work on API 19... and 23, but not 21?

So what do I mean by fail?  Well, on API 21, if you press the *play* button, *no sound plays*, and nothing appears to happen (although if you peek at the logcat, ye shall behold all manner of scary native library messages including many "deaths" and even "tombstone" or two).

If you continue to press *play* a second time, the same thing happens, with more internal error messages being generated in logcat... and the third time, you finally get a crash.

The only error I can see that could be related to anything I have control over is the Exception that's caught in Log.i:

> "com.example.boober.stackqmediaplayer I/SFX:
>   error:java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64"

All the other messages and final stack trace are all generated by internal native libraries.

I've googled these errors, read the logcat and MediaPlayer documentation.  Hopefully I'm just doing something fundamentally stupid that someone can point out to me.

I was really hoping maybe someone out there can take a look.

I've whittled up a very minimal example of the problem that should be very easy to cut/paste/rebuild in Android Studio so you can reproduce the problem:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer ourPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ourPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundeffect);
    }

    public void play(View v) {
        try {
            ourPlayer.stop();
            ourPlayer.prepare();
            ourPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("SFX", "error:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="PLAY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Res Folder (use any audio file):

[image]

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.boober.stackqmediaplayer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it's missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MediaPlayer's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer):

1. `ourPlayer` starts in the **initialized** state, not in the **idle** state, because you used `MediaPlayer.create()`.
2. From the state graph, you can call `stop()` only when the player is playing or paused, but the first time your button click method runs, your player is initialized only, so your calling `stop()` puts your player in the error state, not the stopped state.
3. Your call to `prepare()` in the error state, `IOException` or `IllegalStateException` or  may be thrown. The docs don't say when the former is thrown, but it is caught in your `try-catch`. The latter makes your app crash the third time you click the play button.

The solution is to call `stop()` only when the player is **playing** or **paused**, because these are the states that have a direct arrow to the stopped state.

`MediaPlayer` has an `isPlaying()` method, but there's no `isPaused()`. Some workarounds to this problem may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167731/android-how-to-know-if-mediaplayer-is-paused)

So below is my proposed solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer ourPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ourPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beer03);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ourPlayer.release(); // Free native resources
    }

    public void play(View ignored) {
        try {
            if (ourPlayer.isPlaying() || isPlaybackPaused()) {
                ourPlayer.stop();
                ourPlayer.prepare();
            }
            player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("SFX", "error:" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private boolean isPlaybackPaused() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I tested this out (without the isPaused() check) and it works!  I don't think I will need an isPaused() because I never pause the playback... do you think I would need that for some reason?  I wonder why API 21 is the only API that is affected by my error.

Comment: Glad to know it works! I just mentioned isPaused() for the sake of completion, so in your case it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: As for why API 21 is the only one not to work I can only guess, but actually I wonder why the others do work, because the original code didn't go through the state graph like it should. This flexible behavior was misleading  in this case, but fortunately you took the time to try every API level

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the exact same use case as me...

That you only need the sound to play from the beginning any time the button is pressed (or event triggered)...

I have found another simple solution/workaround that seems to work:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ourPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundeffect);

    }

public void play(View v) {

        if (ourPlayer != null) {
        ourPlayer.release(); }
        ourPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundeffect);
        ourPlayer.start();

    }
```

Please anyone let me know if this is a bad idea for some reason! Thank You!