# MediaPlayer.pause() not working in Moto G Turbo Edition Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have made one sample application in which is just having two buttons
1. Start (to Start music)
2. Stop (to stop music).

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mp = MediaPlayer
                .create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.button_start:
                startAlarm();
                break;
            case R.id.button_stop:
                stopAlarm();
        }
    }

    private void stopAlarm() {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            Log.e("XXX","Tone Paused");
            mp.pause();
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(mp.isPlaying()){
                    Log.e("XXX", "tone still playing ...");
                }
                Log.e("XXX", "Thread stopped");
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void startAlarm() {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Now I saw that mp.pause() is being called and mp.isPlaying() is returning false after that. But the music is continuously playing it never stops until I power off the device.

I am not sure whether this is a bug of android os or hardware. I checked with other android 6.0 devices but it was working fine.

Can someone please suggest me the possible root cause of this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your  stopAlarm()  method

```
    private void stopAlarm() {
    if(mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }      
    }
```

Comment: Please check the logs:

STOP Button Pressed:
-------------------------------
03-03 15:41:59.746 14518-14518/com.example.testmarshmallow E/XXX: Tone Paused
------------------------------------
But in actual tone is still playing.
Again press STOP Button:
-----------------------------------
03-03 15:42:02.010 14518-14518/com.example.testmarshmallow E/XXX: Thread started
03-03 15:42:02.012 14518-18325/com.example.testmarshmallow E/XXX: Thread stopped

Comment: Its working as resource itself is being released. But my question is why pause() is not working. Please help me to find that out.

Comment: Besides if I do stop() the I will again have to call create() -> prepare() which will be time consuming.

Comment: pause() method states it will resume playing from the current position, I'd expect it get back to the beginning when stop() is called.refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849045/mediaplayer-instance-stop-behaves-like-a-pause

Comment: I got your point. But my problem is after pause() is called music is not getting paused. I understand that I can use stop() instead. But why pause() is not pausing the music?